# jquery animate with flexible Property

Tags: javascript, jquery

This will always fail, because argument animate_property stays "animate_property" because its wrapped in a object. How to solve this Problem?

```
AnimateIt("height",100);

function AnimateIt(animate_property, val)
{
    $(".selector").animate({animate_property:val},500);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create your object and apply the key and value prior to calling the `animate()` method. You can set the object key using bracket notation:

```
AnimateIt("height",100);

function AnimateIt(animate_property, val)
{
    animObj = {};
    animObj[animate_property] = val;
    $(".selector").animate(animObj ,500);
}
```

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oGeez/b6d2P/)

Comment: Yeah nice. Work like a charm.

Comment: Glad to have helped (:

Answer (score 0):

You may use `eval()`:

```
AnimateIt("height",100);

function AnimateIt(animate_property, val){
    eval('$(".selector").animate({'+animate_property+':'+val+'},500)');
}
```

or use an object

```
AnimateIt("height",100);

function AnimateIt(animate_property, val){
    var o={};
    o[animate_property] = val;
    $(".selector").animate(o,500);
}
```

Comment: Better to use an object!

Comment: Yes it's better I do know.